# Unable to add exchange email account on LG G3 with Android 4.4.2

Tags: exchange, lg-g3

I keep getting the message "Login information incorrect. Try again". But the login info is most definitely correct. My work IT department confirmed the domain, port, and server address, and my username/pword were correct. Online search results showed this may be a known issue going back more than a year as described here: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/kitkat-causes-activesync-headaches-android-users, but none of the fixes described seem to apply to my phone. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: No problems here with exchange account on LG G3.  I'd double check the domain, port, and server address!  Follow these steps:  http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-113047/

Answer (score 1):

Login to your email on the Web.  Check Settings > Options . There might be an option such as "Connect Devices & Apps with POP".  Ensure that this is set to Enable.

I had the same issue when setting up a Windows Live email on an LG G3.  Once the POP setting was Enabled, the email email account set up worked fine.

Good Luck.